# sqlite commit performance problem with indexes

Tags: c#, windows, sqlite

I have run into a problem where the time to do a commit starts taking
longer and longer. We are talking on the orders of 250ms for a table
with ~ 20k lines and a disc size of around 2-3mb. And it just keeps getting worse. I have tracked the
performance problem down to something to do with indexs. It's almost
as if sqlite is creating the index on every commit. The commit consists of
100 INSERTS. I have made a as small program as I could where I can
reproduce the problem and have tried running this on Linux as well.
There the problem doesn't seem to occur. The problem exists with both
WAL and truncate journaling mode. The problem doesn't seem to exist
when I use a memory database instead of a file. I have tried both
version 3.6.23.1 and 3.7.6.3.

On Windows where I'm experiencing the problem I run sqlite in a C#
program. I have checked the implementation of transaction support in
the System.Date.Sqlite wrapper and it does absolutely nothing else
than simply to a COMMIT. Sadly I don't have a C compiler for Windows
so I can't check it when not running the wrapper, but it should be the
same.

```
System.IO.File.Delete("test.db");

var db_connection = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=test.db");

db_connection.Open();

using (var cmd = db_connection.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE test (id integer primary key, dato integer)";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd.CommandText = "CREATE INDEX i on test(dato)";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}

SQLiteTransaction trans = null;

List<string> paths = new List<string>();

var random = new Random();

for (var j = 0; j < 150; ++j)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
    {
        if (i % 100 == 0)
        {
            trans = db_connection.BeginTransaction();
        }

        using (var cmd = db_connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = String.Format("INSERT INTO test (dato) values ({0})", random.Next(1, 100000000));
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        if (i % 100 == 99 && trans != null)
        {
            var now = DateTime.Now;

            trans.Commit();
            trans.Dispose();

            System.Console.WriteLine("commit {0}", (DateTime.Now - now).TotalMilliseconds);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It appears that the problem is related to the insertion of random numbers. If I change it to insert j * 1000 + i, the performance is fine. But what does one do, when you can't order your results beforehand so that they fit neatly. Do you disable the indexes until you're finished adding the elements you need?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try reducing hard disk access, for example adding this command before creating any table:

```
cmd.CommandText = "PRAGMA locking_mode = EXCLUSIVE";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Providing your app allows exclusive locking of the database.

Also can help:

```
PRAGMA Synchronous=OFF
```